# Is there any straightforward way to fetch and send `current method name` as argument in java?

Tags: java, methods, reflection, java-8

Making an api to log and provide common methods.

```
public static void start(Class<?> clazz) throws IOException {
    writeExecutionLog("Start of" + clazz.getName(), null);
}

public static void end(Class<?> clazz) throws IOException {
    writeExecutionLog("End of" + clazz.getName(), null);
}
```

In classes, There are multiple schedulers in different methods which calls above start and end when job is started or finsihed.

```
class scheduler{

 public void scheduler1(){
    MyService.start(methodname or class)
    MyService.end(methodname or class)
 }

 public void scheduler2(){
    MyService.start(methodname or class)
    MyService.end(methodname or class)
 }
}
```

In place of String, is there any simple way to pass Method name with class name in above start and end method.

I want to fetch current method name dynamically in Start and end methods something like this.class.currentMethod?(not complicated statement like mentioned in geekofgeeks and better if i can handle most of things in start() and end())

Comment: This should be able to help you out https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-name-of-current-method-being-executed-in-java/

Comment: @Stultuske: I have seen this but i dont want client to put that complicated statements. Can i handle at my end in Start End?

Comment: You don’t want to do what @Stultuske posted, but accepted an answer that shows exactly that? By the way, your examples look like you are reinventing a logging API. There are already multiple logging APIs, including the one provided by Java itself, which provide that functionality for free…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate a stack trace and parse the line. It's versatile but expensive.

```
public static void start() throws IOException {
    writeExecutionLog("Start of" + new Throwable().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName(), null);
}
```

Comment: Ok. I have just used your way and found able to find name. Will this always work for all calls. With expensive you means?

Comment: @fatherazrael `new Throwable().getStackTrace()` will create a snapshot of the entire call stack and convert it to a form that the Java application can process (an array of `StackTraceElement` instances. All that, only to read exactly one of those elements and extract an information that is actually fixed at compile-time already. That’s what “expensive” means.

Answer (score 1):

```
String methodName = new Object() {}
  .getClass()
  .getEnclosingMethod()
  .getName();
```

in your method should work.

Comment: Will client pass whole method?

Comment: Just the name. if there is a method hello() it will have hello in the string

Comment: Thanks but i am looking for something else like if end user pass class name to start and i can fetch method name inside that. I can't ask clients to fetch method names like that. They will say it is okay we will pass method name as String too appended with CLASSNAME.METHODNAME.....

Comment: You could use that approach with `MyService.start(new Object {})` and extract the name of the enclosing method inside your `start` implementation.

Comment: @ArvidHeise: So at end i again need to call MyService.end(new Object{}). Not sure this will be acceptable by programmers.  I have just used way in your answer and found able to find name. Will this always work for all calls. With expensive you means?

Comment: Generating a stack trace costs quite a bit CPU time, especially when the call stack increases.

Answer (score 1):

You are reinventing the wheel, as logging APIs do already exist and are capable of identifying the method.

Taking the built-in logging API `java.util.logging.*`, a very simple example demonstrating the capability would be

```
public class MethodNameExample1 {
    static final Logger MY_SERVICE = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
    static {
        MY_SERVICE.setUseParentHandlers(false);
        MY_SERVICE.addHandler(new Handler() {
            public void publish(LogRecord lr) {
                System.out.println(lr.getSourceClassName()+"."+lr.getSourceMethodName()
                                  +" "+lr.getMessage()+"ed");
            }
            public void flush() {}
            public void close() {}
        });
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MY_SERVICE.info("enter");
        firstExample();
        Inner.thirdExample();
        MY_SERVICE.info("exit");
    }
    static void firstExample() {
        MY_SERVICE.info("enter");
        secondExample();
        MY_SERVICE.info("exit");
    }
    static void secondExample() {
        MY_SERVICE.info("enter");
        MY_SERVICE.info("exit");
    }
    static class Inner {
        static void thirdExample() {
            MY_SERVICE.info("enter");
            //...
            MY_SERVICE.info("exit");
        }
    }
}
```

```
MethodNameExample1.main entered
MethodNameExample1.firstExample entered
MethodNameExample1.secondExample entered
MethodNameExample1.secondExample exited
MethodNameExample1.firstExample exited
MethodNameExample1$Inner.thirdExample entered
MethodNameExample1$Inner.thirdExample exited
MethodNameExample1.main exited
```

When you want to have more control over this (or insist on creating your own logging API implementation), Java 9’s `StackWalker` is the way to go. Unlike capturing a stack trace like with `new Throwable().getStackTrace()`, the stack walker supports extracting only the needed information, including hinting about the maximum number of frames we intend to traverse, so the JVM doesn’t need to process more than necessary and may apply further optimizations:

```
public class MethodNameExample2 {
    public static class MyService {
        private static final StackWalker STACK_WALKER=StackWalker.getInstance(Set.of(), 3);
        public static void enter() {
            System.out.println(getCaller()+" entered");
        }
        public static void exit() {
            System.out.println(getCaller()+" exited");
        }
        private static String getCaller() {
            return STACK_WALKER.walk(frames -> frames.skip(2)
                .map(f -> f.getClassName()+'.'+f.getMethodName())
                .findFirst().orElse("unknown caller"));
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyService.enter();
        firstExample();
        Inner.thirdExample();
        MyService.exit();
    }
    static void firstExample() {
        MyService.enter();
        secondExample();
        MyService.exit();
    }
    static void secondExample() {
        MyService.enter();
        MyService.exit();
    }
    static class Inner {
        static void thirdExample() {
            MyService.enter(); MyService.exit();
        }
    }
}
```

```
MethodNameExample2.main entered
MethodNameExample2.firstExample entered
MethodNameExample2.secondExample entered
MethodNameExample2.secondExample exited
MethodNameExample2.firstExample exited
MethodNameExample2$Inner.thirdExample entered
MethodNameExample2$Inner.thirdExample exited
MethodNameExample2.main exited
```

Answer (score 0):

Your task should be done using AOP (Aspect oriented programming)

> [AOP] aims to increase modularity by allowing the separation of cross-cutting concerns. It does so by adding additional behavior to existing code (an advice) without modifying the code itself, instead separately specifying which code is modified via a "pointcut" specification, such as **"log all function calls when the function's name begins with 'set'"**.

For example, you can mark all your scheduler methods with a custom annotation (or use method name, package name etc.) and the create an aspect

```
@Around("@annotation(LogExecutionTime)")
public Object logExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
   logger.debug("start of ...")
   Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();
   logger.debug("end of ...")
   return proceed;
}
```

from `ProceedingJoinPoint` you can extract a lot of information not just method name.